# Unexpected change of list values

Tags: python, list

This is my class:

```
class variable(object):
    def __init__(self, name, name_alias, parents,values,table):
        #name of the variable
        self.name = ""
```

This is the function with problems:

`f` is a .txt file (opened in `main` function),

```
def read_problem(f):
    list_of_variables=[]
    entry=0;

    for line in f:
        words = line.split()

        #enters only if it's not a comment
        if (words[0]!='#'):

            if (words[0]=="VAR"):
                x=variable;
            elif (words[0]=="name"):
                x.name=words[1]
                list_of_variables.append(x)

    for i in range(len(list_of_variables)):
        print(list_of_variables[i].name)
    return
```

My .txt file is:

```
VAR
name MaryCalls
VAR
name JohnCalls
VAR
name Burglary
VAR
name Earthquake
VAR
name Alarm
```

What I get in that print(and thus, the list) is:

```
Alarm
Alarm
Alarm
Alarm
Alarm
```

But I wanted to have:

```
MaryCalls
JohnCalls
Burglary
Earthquake
Alarm
```

What's wrong? Why are all the previous entries of the list changing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `x=variable` makes the `x` refer to the class `variable`. You never create any instances of that class, instead you repeatedly modify a class-level variable `name`.

At the end of the program, when you print, `variable.name` of course has the last value assigned to it, in this case `'Alarm'`.

You'll see this if you do `print(list_of_variables)`:

```
[<class '__main__.variable'>, <class '__main__.variable'>,
```

etc.

Change `x = variable` to `x = variable()`, and you'll see (for example):

```
[<__main__.variable object at 0x6ffffee65d0>, <__main__.variable object at 0x6ffffee6610>
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you want to initialize the name in the constructor of `variable`, you have to indent the assignment further.

```
def __init__(self, name, name_alias, parents,values,table):
    #name of the variable
    self.name = ""
```

2) Your main problem is, that you want to create a new instance of `variable` with this line:

```
x=variable;
```

You have to write:

```
x = variable();
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is when the code detects a line starting with "VAR" it assigns the class variable to x, not an instance of the class. To do that you need to call the class which ends up invoking the class' `__init__()` method if it has one. Yours does, but it expects 5 arguments, none of which are known at that time of creation.

The easiest thing to do in such a case is to assign each argument a default value that means "doesn't have a value yet", and assign those to the instance being created (`self`).

Here's what I mean:

```
class Variable(object):
    def __init__(self, name="", name_alias="", parents=None, values=None, 
                 table=None):
        self.name = name
        self.name_alias = name_alias
        self.parents = parents
        self.values = values
        self.table = table

def read_problem(f):
    list_of_Variables=[]

    for line in f:
        words = line.split()

        # if not a comment
        if words[0] != '#':
            if words[0] == "VAR":
                x = Variable()  # construct empty Variable
            elif words[0] == "name":
                x.name = words[1]
                list_of_Variables.append(x)

    for var in list_of_Variables:
        print(var.name)
    return

def main():
    filename = 'variables.txt'
    with open(filename) as f:
        read_problem(f)

main()
```