# Assigning Variables in While loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm using a While loop in a script that loops over a directory, looks for new files in the directory and does an action on the added files; and if there are no added files the while loop breaks and the script ends.  However, I'm having a bit of trouble with the variable assignments in the loop. I'm trying to get one variable take the values of variable 2, and then delete the contents of the second variable.  However, when I try to get new variables for variable 2, variable 1 takes those variables again before it reaches that part of the code, thus signifying a break in the while loop.

```
before = []
after = []

while True:
    time.sleep(60)

    for folder in folders:
        files = os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder))
        for f in files:
            after.append(f)

    added = [f for f in after if f not in before]
    if not added:
        break

    for f in added:
        ## do some action ##

    before = after
    del after[:]
    del added[:]
```

The while loop breaks during its second iteration, and when checking the variables, the `before` and `after` variables are the same (both having the files that include the ones added in the second iteration). Since the loop hasn't yet reached the part where `before` takes the `after` contents in the second iteration, why does it have those values?

Comment: why are you using `del` ?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20455200/2588818. `before = after` means `before` now refers to the list `after` previously pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `before = after` line essentially causes `before` and `after` to point to the same underlying list:

```
In [15]: a = [1,2,3]

In [16]: b = a

In [17]: id(a), id(b)
Out[17]: (4350556208, 4350556208)

In [18]: del a[:]

In [19]: a.append(4)

In [20]: b
Out[20]: [4]
```

You can fix this by either using the `copy` library or just doing a short copy of your own:

```
In [24]: a = [1,2,3]

In [25]: b = [e for e in a]

In [26]: id(a), id(b)
Out[26]: (4349521576, 4349826040)
```

Comment: `b = a[:]` or `b = list(a)` is probably a better approach than the list comprehension.

Comment: I'd say `b = a[:]` is most clear as to what the caller is doing: making an explicit copy of the list. It's also short and readable and reasonable. All this is of course `caveat`ed by the elements of `a`. If they aren't primitives (is that what Python calls these? I can't remember anymore), then they'll be pointers to objects, which may or may not be what a given user wants.